# while loop won't break,should break when the counter is no longer less than the length of the array

Tags: python, while-loop, counter, break

trying to compare items in a and b and return greatest number at each index in list big - result should be [9,14,9,14,15,18,15].doing this for a class, must use while loop and counter

```
a = [7,12,9,14,15,18,12]
b = [9,14,8,3,15,17,15]
big = []
i = 0
length = len(a)
while i < length:
    if a[i] > b[i]:
        big.append(a[i])
    else:
        big.append(b[i])
    i = i + 1
print(big)
```

Comment: what is your problem? a and b has the same size?

Comment: It does break. What makes you think that it doesn't? Also, you can do this much better with `map`: `map(max, zip(a, b))`.

Comment: You've missed a crucial piece of information: what language is this? It's best to include it in the tags associated to the question, so people who know that language will spot it sooner.

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment in pseudocode to me.  There might not be a real language.

Comment: @curtisdf it is valid Python :)

Comment: I see.  You can tell I don't know Python.  ;-)

Comment: @curtisdf don't worry Python is *meant* to look like pseudocode

Comment: @user2465307 The code is valid. 

You probably just encountered SyntaxError when you run it directly in the python interpretor. You should post the exact error message as nachokk suggested

Comment: I have pasted each line and block in Python Idle and it works fine.

Comment: i didn't get an error, I am trying to run in pyscripter and it just keeps running and I have to kill the program. why would that be

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code directly in the python shell, you will get a SyntaxError.

For more info, see http://bugs.python.org/issue11433

If you save the code down in a file, say test.py, then run `python test.py`, it will print out the result as expected.

Edit:

This answer is currently having a -1 rating. Before you downvote, can you actually read and try to understand the answer?

This is what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: -1.  There is nothing wrong with using the above code in a Python shell. It does exactly what OP expects.

Comment: sorry forgot to specify this is python, i am running it in pyscripter and it appears as though it doesnt break i have to kill the program

Comment: @dansalmo I don't think you have actually tried it inside a python interpretor. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: @Anthony Kong: The problem you are seeing is completely different than the problem OP is asking about.  Your problem has to do with the manner in which you are entering the code.

Comment: @dansalmo Given the limited information provided by OP, it is the most likely error he has encountered. And in fact his problem is with an interactive session, not a code itself.

Comment: @dansalmo I don't think you have any experience or interest to understand and help beginners. They are often unable to state the problem clearly or attach error message. And while you are here, why don't you downvote other similar answers?

Comment: @Anthony Kong:  OP has already told you above that your answer did not address the issue.  I can tell your having difficulty accepting the downvote so I will take it back.  I very rarely downvote, and always explain why to help people improve answers.  I do have the interest but obviously not the experience to help everyone see their errors. :)  I have no idea what you are referring to regarding similar answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code. I just copied it and ran through the IDLE. Output is exactly as you specified

Comment: i didn't get an error, I am trying to run in pyscripter and it just keeps running and I have to kill the program. why would that be

Comment: That is not happening for anyone else.  I would add a `print i, length` statement in the loop and see what it is doing.

Comment: The problem might be with pyscripter.

Comment: problem seemed to be with the if clause, rewritten this way works

Comment: a = [7,12,9,14,15,18,12]
b = [9,14,8,3,15,17,15]
i = 0
big = []
length = len(a)
while i < length:
    big.append(max(a[i],b[i]))
    i = i + 1
print(big)

Comment: Glad you got it working, `big.append(max(a[i],b[i]))` is cleaner as well, but there was nothing wrong with your `if` clause above.  The issue was something else.